# How to supress b'' character when accessing HDF5 file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5

So I'm trying to access entries in subdirectories in a HDF5 file. Below is my code

```
data = h5py.File(filename, 'r')

    seqTags = []
    for entry in data['somesebdir']:
        seqTags.append(str(entry).replace("b'", "")[:-1])
        seq_list_file.append(str(entry).replace("b'", "")[:-1])
```

As you can see I'm using `replace` to get with of `` b'something'` to get `` something`. However I would like to avoid doing this. How do I just get the content within HDF5 file without having to worry about this` b''``` character?

I've already tried accessing it with `rb` option. It was still the same.

Comment: It would be great if you can convert this in a reproducible example. Now we can only guess if `entry` is a group or a dataset. Maybe you can add some lines in which you generate the file, and then use these lines to read it. Otherwise comments here remain a bit vague and uncertain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* the problem is that you actually have a `bytes` object being returned (I can't be sure without reproducing it with your data).  The problem is you don't want to use `str()` to decode the bytes, because that's what's giving you the 'b' in the first place.  Instead use `entry.decode()` to convert the `bytes` to a `str`.